# How to get rid of background arts in Chrome Themes from Chrome Store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, chrome-web-store

There is a whole slew of themes in Chrome Store. Many have pleasant colors for Chrome skin but unfortunately go with useless background images or wallpapers.

How to install a theme and then get rid of its fancy background image? I only want to get colors for Chrome skin from a theme, not a background.

[image]